# How to use JOIN correctly

Tags: sql

Can someone help me with this? I am new to SQL.

I want to return one record for every record in `Product_Entity`.

`Product_Entity` is linked to `Entity_Varchar` by the common column `entity_id`.

I want each record in the results to include `Entity_Varchar.value`, but only when `Entity_Varchar.attribute_id = ‘73’` as there will be many records in `Entity_Varchar` that will match on `entity_id`, but only one where also `Entity_Varchar.attribute_id=’73’`

```
SELECT
    Product_Entity.sku AS SKU,
    Entity_Varchar.value AS Description
FROM
    Product_Entity
JOIN
    Entity_Varchar ON Entity_Varchar.entity_id = Entity_Varchar.entity_id
WHERE 
    Entity_Varchar.attribute_id = '73'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query basically looks right.  However, if you want *all* rows in the first table, then use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT pe.sku AS SKU, ev.value AS Description
FROM Product_Entity pe LEFT JOIN
     Entity_Varchar ev
     ON ev.entity_id = pe.entity_id AND
        ev.attribute_id = '73';
```

Rows that don't match will have `NULL` for the description.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is correct you just misspelled table name. Instead of `Product_Entity` you used `Entity_Varchar` in both side of on clause.

Corrected query:

```
SELECT Product_Entity.sku AS SKU, Entity_Varchar.value AS Description FROM Product_Entity inner Join Entity_Varchar 
ON Product_Entity.entity_id = Entity_Varchar.entity_id
WHERE Entity_Varchar.attribute_id = '73'
```

For better readability you can use table aliaces.

```
SELECT pe.sku AS SKU, ev.value AS Description 
FROM Product_Entity pe inner Join Entity_Varchar ev
ON pe.entity_id = ev.entity_id
WHERE ev.attribute_id = '73'
```

If you want to select rows from Product_Entity table even when there is no row in Entity_Varchar table with same entity_id and for attribute_id 73 you need to use left join instead of inner join.

```
SELECT pe.sku AS SKU, ev.value AS Description 
FROM Product_Entity pe left Join Entity_Varchar ev
ON pe.entity_id = ev.entity_id
WHERE ev.attribute_id = '73'
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you need, you want every record from Product_Entity, whether or not it has an attribute_id = 73 record on Entity_Varchar.  But if there is an attibute_id = 73 record on Entity_Varchar, you want the description from that row also.

First, you need a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to get all of the records from Product_Entity, not filtered by the contents of Entity_Varchar.
Then, you need to filter Entity_Varchar.  But if you place this filter in the `WHERE` clause, it causes the join to become an `INNER JOIN`.  (I see error a lot.  I call it a "LEFT INNER JOIN".  Of course, that's not a real thing.)  To overcome this, put the filter in the join logic.  Then it's filtered before being joined.

```
SELECT Product_Entity.sku AS SKU
, Entity_Varchar.value AS Description

FROM Product_Entity
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Entity_Varchar ON Entity_Varchar.entity_id = Entity_Varchar.entity_id
                                AND Entity_Varchar.attribute_id = '73'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is correct you just misspelled table name. Instead of Product_Entity you used Entity_Varchar in both side of on clause.

```
SELECT Product_Entity.sku AS SKU, Entity_Varchar.value AS Description FROM Product_Entity inner Join Entity_Varchar 
ON Product_Entity.entity_id = Entity_Varchar.entity_id
WHERE Entity_Varchar.attribute_id = '73'
```